# bounded operators and rank equal 1

Tags: linear-transformations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have a new question:
If $X$ is an Hilbert space, and

1. $C\in L(X,\mathbb{C})$
2. $B\in L(\mathbb{C},X)$
3. $(sI-A)^{-1}\in L(X)$ , where $A$ is a generator of an holomorphic semigroup

Can I conclude that
$$
rank(C(sI-A)^{-1}B)=1 ?
$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $B$ is at most rank-one, and composition cannot increase rank, you have that 
$$
\operatorname{rank}(C(sI-A)^{-1}B)\leq 1. 
$$ 
But a priori you cannot discard that $C(sI-A)^{-1}B$ is zero. Even if $B\ne0$, the range of $(sI-A)^{-1}B$ is one-dimensional; it is enough to choose $C$ such that it is zero on the (one-dimensional) range of $(sI-A)^{-1}B$ to get $C(sI-A)^{-1}B=0$